# Doesn't call newly created view in mvc 4 even view is exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a new view created button in older view. I can't open new view neither from Action nor from url.

```
Controller: HomeController
OlderView: Index (View/Home/Index.cshtml)
Action: Success
NewView: Success  (View/Home/Success.cshtml)
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Success", "Home")'" />
```

HomeController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Success()
{
    //return View(); //this also doesn't work
    return View("Success");
}
```

Success.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Success";
}

<h2>Your transaction has been completed successfully.</h2>
```

If I try directly from url: http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/Home/Success, it throw following error

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Home/Success
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1

Can anybody suggest me what I am missing here? Do I need to register the view anywhere?

Comment: remove `[HttpPost]` attribute from `Success` controller action.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla it's done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a view means that request is get request but you write view as httpPost ...
So change action as HttpGet
or
call with button click or any other post actions...